# Styling Android Material Time Picker

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-timepicker

I'm new here and seeking guidance on styling a time picker to match a specific design. I'm working on a Android kotlin project, and I want to achieve a look similar to the following image:
[image]

However, I'm facing challenges in replicating this appearance. I'm particularly unsure about how to adjust the layout, colors, and fonts to match the design in the image.

I've explored various resources and documentation but haven't found a solution that fits my requirements. Could someone please provide guidance or suggest approaches to achieve the desired styling for the time picker?

Thank you for your assistance!

Edit :
I have found the way to edit the header, still searching for another component

```
<style name="CustomMaterialTimePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <item name="materialTimePickerTitleStyle">@style/TextAppearance.App.TimePicker.Title</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.App.TimePicker.Title" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/red_hat_display_bold</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Doesn't the default time picker already look pretty close to what you're achieving, or am I missing something?

Comment: yeah, sorry to bother you, its because previously i have set a style in theme that affect this time picker, now its good